# Good example for comparison between Guided and Gaussian filters

Tags: matlab, image-processing, filter, computer-vision

I am looking for a good example that showing the different between Guided and Gaussian Filters. The example need to show the benefit of Guided filter, (for example: preserving edge...). Could you give me some example for that task? Thanks in advance

I tried some example, but it did not show benefit of Guided comparison with Gaussian

```
% example: edge-preserving smoothing
% figure 1 in our paper

close all;

I = double(imread('.\img_smoothing\cat.bmp')) / 255;
I = imnoise(I,'gaussian',0.1,0);
p = I;
r = 4; % try r=2, 4, or 8
eps = 0.2^2; % try eps=0.1^2, 0.2^2, 0.4^2

q = guidedfilter(I, p, r, eps);
std_Gb=1;
beta=0.1;
%% Initialization 
Ng=ceil(3*std_Gb)+1; Gaussian = fspecial('gaussian',[Ng Ng],std_Gb);
imsm = conv2(I,Gaussian,'same');

[Gx,Gy] = gradient(q );
NormGrad = sqrt(Gx.^2 + Gy.^2); 
Gb1 = 1./ (1 + 1* NormGrad.^2);

[Gx,Gy] = gradient(imsm);
NormGrad = sqrt(Gx.^2 + Gy.^2); 
Gb2= 1./ (1 + 1* NormGrad.^2);

figure();
subplot(2,1,1);imshow([I, q,imsm],[]);
subplot(2,1,2);imshow([Gb1,Gb2],[]);
```

[image]

Comment: `double(img)/255` is equal to `im2double`

Comment: It does not matter. It is only normalization

Comment: right. im2double do that.

Comment: But i am interesting in the why the guided filter is left side can preserve edge than Gaussian is in right side

Comment: my comment was just FYI. you can ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

If I read your example correctly, I think you're already showing what you need to. The Gaussian blurred image (center) has far less edge detail than the guided filter version (right), which also shows some smoothing.

Comment: Sorry. I did not title the image. The guided filter is left side and Gaussian is right side